# Why does my method that merges two array lists of strings together and sorts them keep returning multiple coppies of the strings at each index?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, junit4

Here is my method. For this assignment, we were not allowed to use any of the "collections" methods like sort. My thought process goes as follows; first I make the new ArrayList by adding the two ArrayLists into it. Next, I do another for-loop and a value swap.

```
public static ArrayList<String> mergeStrings(ArrayList<String> list1, ArrayList<String> list2) {
        
        ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++) {
                
                newList.add(list1.get(i));
                newList.add(list2.get(j));
        }
    }
                
        String temp;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < newList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < newList.size(); j++) {
                
                if (newList.get(i).compareTo(newList.get(j)) > 0) {
                   
                    temp = newList.get(i);
                    newList.set(i, newList.get(j));
                    newList.set(j, temp);
                }
            }
        }
        return newList;
    }
```

My JUnit test case, and its results:

```
@Test
    public void testMergeStrings2() {
        ArrayList<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a1.add("ant");
        a1.add("elephant");
        a1.add("camel");
        ArrayList<String> a2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        a2.add("deer");
        a2.add("bear");
        a2.add("frog");
        ArrayList<String> merged = new ArrayList<String>();
        merged.add("ant");
        merged.add("bear");
        merged.add("camel");
        merged.add("deer");
        merged.add("elephant");
        merged.add("frog");
        assertEquals(merged, ListUtilities.mergeStrings(a1, a2));
    }
```

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[ant, bear, camel, deer, elephant, frog]> but was:<[ant, ant, ant, bear, bear, bear, camel, camel, camel, deer, deer, deer, elephant, elephant, elephant, frog, frog, frog]>
    

As you can see from above, my test cases are obtaining multiple copies of each of the elements in the list. I'm sure that the problem lies within my for-loop disaster, but everything I do seems to make it much worse. Any help is appreciated!
```

Comment: The top loops should not be nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are putting a for loop in another one.
It should've been

```java
for (int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){
   newList.get(list1.get(i));
}
for (int j=0;j<list2.size();j++){
   newList.get(list2.get(j));
}
```

Because currently, for every element in list2 you fetch the *same* element in list1 again (because the second for loop of j doesn't change i)

Answer (score 0):

The part where you are adding items from both the ArrayLists is causing the duplication of elements.

This is how the new ArrayList looks before you sort it:

["ant", "deer", "ant", "bear", "ant", "frog", "elephant", "deer", "elephant", "bear", "elephant", "frog", "camel", "deer", "camel", "bear", "camel", "frog"]

One possible way to avoid duplication of elements while adding them is

```
public static ArrayList<String> addElements(ArrayList<String> a1, ArrayList<String>     a2){
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i<a1.size(); i++){
        newList.add(a1.get(i));
    }

    //another way to add
    for(String s : a2){
        newList.add(s);
    }
    
    //could also do newList.addAll(a1); newList.addAll(a2) if you were allowed to use collection methods
    return newList;
}
```